# When to add records to a user_posts table to track 'likes'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, activerecord, database-design

I have a Groups model that `has_many` Topics.
The Topics model `has_many` Posts, my Users model only read posts etc.
I also have a users_posts model which is used to keep track whether a user has read the post
and whether they 'liked' the post, it has  :group_id, :user_id and :read and :liked boolean fields.
A user creates a group and adds posts under different topics.

The Groups show action is; 
`@posts = Group.topics.includes(:posts)`

My question is when and how do I add records to the users_posts table?
Should it be when a post is first created?
or only when a user views the post for the first time?

and what is the best way to add the attributes from user_posts to each record in @posts?
at the minute I'm using virtual attributes, is this the right way?

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :topic
  has_many :users, through: :user_entries
  attr_accessor :read, :liked
```

Comment: If you have a lot of users, then adding an entry to the users_posts table for every user every time a new post is created might be too much.

Comment: yes, that's why I'm asking the question!

Comment: Is it relevant a post is read in a specific group? E.g. if a post is in multiple groups?

Comment: @nathanvda no a read counts across all groups

Answer (score 2):

**ID**

Firstly, you won't need to use `:group_id` in your `user_posts` model / table

Rails, and relational databases, use `primary keys` to give elements unique id's. This means regardless of whether a `post` is a member of a `group`, you'll still be referencing it with the `post_id` [foreign key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)  -

```
#users_posts
id | user_id | post_id | read | updated | created_at | updated_at
```

--

**Attributes**

> add the attributes from `user_posts` to each record in `@posts`

The way to do this will be to associate `user_posts` with the `User` and `Post` models -

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :user_posts
   has_many :posts, through: :user_posts
end

#app/models/post.rb
Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :user_posts
   has_many :users, through: :user_posts
end
```

This will allow you to call `@user.posts`

If you want to attach extra attributes to each `post` associative object, you'll need to either use an [ALIAS SQL join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250636/rails-scoping-for-has-many-through-to-access-extra-data), or an [`ActiveRecord Association Extension`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20816020/using-delegate-with-has-many-in-rails):

```
#app/models/post.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :user_posts
   has_many :posts, through: :user_posts, extend: PostUser
end

#app/models/concerns/post_user.rb
module PostUser

    #Load
    def load
        reads.each do |caption|
            proxy_association.target << read
        end
    end

    #Private
    private

    #Attributes
    def captions
        return_array = []
        through_collection.each_with_index do |through,i|
            associate = through.send(reflection_name)
            associate.assign_attributes({read: items[i]}) if items[i].present?
            return_array.concat Array.new(1).fill( associate )
        end
        return_array
    end

    #######################
    #      Variables      #
    #######################

    #Association
    def reflection_name
        proxy_association.source_reflection.name
    end

    #Foreign Key
    def through_source_key
        proxy_association.reflection.source_reflection.foreign_key
    end

    #Primary Key
    def through_primary_key
        proxy_association.reflection.through_reflection.active_record_primary_key
    end

    #Through Name
    def through_name
        proxy_association.reflection.through_reflection.name
    end

    #Through
    def through_collection
        proxy_association.owner.send through_name
    end

    #Captions
    def items
        through_collection.map(&:read)
    end

    #Target
    def target_collection
        #load_target
        proxy_association.target
    end

end
```

--

**System**

Bottom line is I think your system will be best run like this:

```
1. Set up a semi-persistent data store to track user / post reads (REDIS)
2. Every time you call a `Post`, you'll be able to call the associated `REDIS` references for it
```

This will give you the ability to create a system which is firstly modular, but you can also create an instance method to determine whether a user has read the post or not, like this:

```
#app/models/post.rb
Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   def read?
      ##Redis lookup for user with post - if "read" attribute is true, return true
   end

   def liked?
      ##Redis lookup for user with post - if "liked" attribute is true, return true
   end
end
```

This will allow you to run `@user.posts.first.read?`

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer but a user will only see posts within the context of the group, users don't create posts only read them, they come from an external source. The redis solution looks like the best way to handle likes etc.

Comment: also why do you say the redis store is semi persistent?

Comment: Hey Raphael, being honest, I was a little confused with the setup, so I just figured I'd post anything which may help

Comment: Because Redis is basically like RAM - it's only meant to store data for a period, before committing to a permanent way of keeping it. That's how I see it anyway (it's why lots of the queuing systems in Rails are done with Redis)

Comment: Further to my last comment - the "RAM" idea would be like if you wanted to keep the likes for the current month. You'll keep them in a REDIS instance, and then after the month, commit them to the DB